# Gordan’s lemma equivalent statement

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $A$ be an $m × n$ matrix. Recall that Gordan’s lemma states that the
system
$$\{d : Ad < 0\}$$ 
is inconsistent if and only if the system
$$λ ≥ 0 ∈ R ^m , λ \not= 0, A ^T λ = 0$$
is consistent.

---

Show that the consistency of the second system is equivalent to the
statement that $0 ∈ C$
 2. Use a separation argument to prove that $\{d : Ad < 0\} = ∅$ if and
only if $ 0 \notin C$, thereby proving Gordan’s lemma

## Proof so far

$\Rightarrow$ Let $C$ be the convex hull of the rows of $A$, that is, $C = co(a_1 , . . . , a_m ) ⊆ E$,where $a_i$ is the ith row of $A$. Suppose the second system is consistent. We want to show that $0 \in C$.
If $A^{T}=[a_1,a_2,...,a_m]$.
Then $A^{T}\lambda=\sum_{i=1}^{m}a_i\lambda_i=0$.
Therefore $O \in C$

Comment: I need help showing these statements are equivalent

Comment: I am not sure if my proof is accurate

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: How do you prove the other direction @PaulSinclair

Comment: @PaulSinclair Or it  is correct that my proof isn’t accurate?

Comment: Sorry - thought you were just asking if what you had so far was correct. I didn't realize you were also asking about going the other way. One element that is missing from what you already have is that you need to state that $$A^T\frac{\lambda}{\sum_i \lambda_i} = 0$$ to directly see that $0 \in C$, since $C$ includes only sums of the $a_i$ where the coefficients sum to $1$. But that is a trivial correction.

Answer (score 1):

For the converse direction, if $0 \in C$, then by definition of the convex hull, there exists $\{\lambda_i\}$ such that $\lambda_i \ge 0$ for all $i$, $\sum \lambda_i = 1$, and $\sum \lambda_ia_i = 0$. But then $\lambda = (\lambda_1, ... \lambda_n)$ is a solution the system, and therefore the system must be consistent.

Edit: Whether the statement above is true by definition or theorem depends exactly on how you define "convex hull". But any common definition implies it. For example: [convex hull and convex combinations equivalence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81320/convex-hull-and-convex-combinations-equivalence?rq=1).